# how to make Url in web service so that i can directly Invoke hello world

Tags: java, web-services, rest

```
package com.hcl.test.ws;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    public String hello() {

        return "Hello This is RestFull Web Service/";

    }
}
```

This is my code and working Perfectly  but i  want deploy its war file in server. currently  i am invoking like this in eclipsed[http://localhost:8080/SecondrestFullClient/sampleHelloWorldProxy/TestClient.jsp] but i want to deploy it in server lcaolhost:8089  server so that every one can use from this please help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it into a war either using a build tool like ant or maven, or if you're using Eclipse just right click on the project and go to "Export - Web - War File".

Then, you should install a local copy of Tomcat on your host.  Change the settings.xml file so it runs on 8089 rather than the default 8080 and you should be able to invoke the service as you mention above.

Comment: every thing i have done i just want to know how i will Invoke what will URL to access it ?

Comment: just open a browser, with `http://localhost:8089/` to get to Tomcat, then after that it's the name of the war file, lets call it test.war, so `http://localhost:8089/test/` then you start querying the endpoints, so from looking at your code above `http://localhost:8089/test/hello`